# jquery: проверка наличия элемента внутри слоя

Tags: jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в jquery проверить наличие тега `<select>` внутри слоя, например `wrap`?

Т.е. можно ли получить булев тип: 'да' или 'нет'?

```
    a = $("#wrap select");
    console.log(a);
```

Вроде находит элемент, но целочисленного значения не получается.

Comment: `a = $("#wrap select").length == 1;`

Comment: `a = ($("#wrap select").length > 0);`